# ASP.Net page only to be accessed from a link

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I have a page in ASP.Net lets call it www.test.com/testPage
I want this page to be accessed by the users who click that link from a certain website, lets call it
www.justtest.com

basically the visitos of www.justtest.com can only view the page www.test.com/testPage

Is this something possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish that by looking at the Referrer on the Request. Something like:

```
if( Request.UrlReferrer.Host != "www.justtest.com" )
{
    // Redirect the user somewhere else
}
```

Comment: Which is easily spoofable. It may or may not matter.

Comment: And referer header is not always passed so may not work for everyone.